# Replacing multiple files in subfolder with cmd

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-console

I have around 200 files with updated version and a lot of subfolders. I need to replace those files into another directory that have same filenames, but older version and also a lot of subfolders, but with different names. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried to use:

```
replace "filepath1"\*.* "filepath2" /s /u
```

Did not worked. As I understand, it can replace if my filepath1 does not have subfolders, but only files available.
I can just pick all those files from Search function and add to different folder, but I am bored and wanted to know if I can do it without adding files into one folder.

I hope someone understands what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share an example of what needs to be done?
For example:
given the following file structure:
C:\TEMP\FILES
├───subFolder1
│       file1.txt
│       file4.txt
│       file5.txt
│
└───subFolder2
        file1.txt
        file2.txt
        file3.txt

how do i copy all files from subFolder1 to subFolder2 without overriding file1.txt

Comment: Ok, so I have Folder1, it has 3 subfolders, those subfolders have another 3-4 subfolders and etc. In each subfolder there are files file1.mqxlz, file2.mqxlz, file3.mqxlz and etc.
Another folder Folder2 have same thing, but older version files with different subfolder names. I want to update Folder2 with files from Folder1.

Comment: Please edit your question and update with the improved description so that other users can understand it easily whiteout looking in the comments. do you want to update the content of file file1.mqxlz? this is exactly what the linux/unix shell command `rsync` does. you can install Windows Subsystem for Linux and then run rsync, an alternative is https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync which should run on windows.